# Identifying a variable and plugging the user-selected value

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

If I have a program that requires the user to input a function, how do I identify the variable in the function and plug into that? For example:

```
Input X: 3
Input Function: 3x + 3
```

So, how would I isolate the x, or in general, just plugin the value for x? Would I have to use a string component separator with isnan()?

EDIT:

OKAY! I got it working using `NSExpression`. So far, it's looking good, a little rough around the edges, but good. Here's what I've run into: I've been trying to continuously add a product to a variable as a for-loop goes from the lower limit to the highest limit.

```
for eachSum in lowLim...upLim{
        let expression = NSExpression(format: funct)
        var result = (expression.expressionValueWithObject(["x":eachSum], context: nil) as NSNumber).floatValue
        println(result)
        sumArray = sumArray + Int(result)
    }
```

I've kind of let myself go in variable names. This is actually supposed to be a sums program, you know, the sums calculated denoted by a capital Sigma. The loop is supposed to go through each lowLim and plug it in and then stop once it reaches upLim. Each time, it adds the product of eachSum to sumArray.

If I were to set `lowLim = 1` and `upLim = 3` and the function was 3*x, I should get 18, but instead, I get 9. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

---

NOTES:

funct = the stringValue of the textField for the function
sumArray = the final answer

Also, excuse the shitty formatting and/or extra stuff added that might not have been needed.

---

EVERYTHING HAS BEEN FIXED! The problem, as stupid as it may sound, was something I didn't take into consideration. I didn't think I could mess this up. I connected the `lowLim` outlet to the *same* textField as `upLim`. Thank you to everyone who helped. Really good learning experience.

Comment: You would need to split the string up and search the characters. Though I'm curious if there's a better way myself.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the `9` vs `18` problem. I always get 18.

Comment: That's odd, because I keep running and testing the program. I never get 18. It's always 9 and I think I've found out why. It seems as though my version of it keeps multiplying `upLim` by 3 (or the coefficient) and sets that as the result. Trying to find a workaround now. --- Yeah, now I'm positive. It sets the value of `x` to `upLim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're talking about inputting mathematical functions and then evaluating them. You would have to decide what operations are supported and the exact syntax users must use to input those functions. This is called a [domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) or DSL.

Once you've decided on your DSL, you will have to write a simple parser for it. This is a huge topic and can be very simple or very complex depending upon how simple or complex your DSL is.

If you're looking for some simple, "out-of-the-box" solution, I'm not aware of anything, though I wouldn't be surprised if it exists. Most likely you will have to roll your own.

Look at Apple's documentation for `NSScanner`. That's a decent start. Some folks have started developing parser combinator libraries for Swift. I won't link to any of them here because it's early days, but try a search engine.

As Trevör Anne Denise mentioned in a comment below, `NSExpression` is another good starting point. (And something I'm going to delve into myself.)

Comment: By the way, NSExpression might be useful to evaluate some math expressions : http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/ EDIT : And it looks like it is also possible to create custom functions.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say I've never heard of `NSExpression` until you just mentioned it. After glancing at that article, I think that would be another place to start.

Comment: Yeah, it's also thanks to this website that I discovered it, surprising that such a handy class isn't more popular.